# Python iteration to subtract one row from another to produce a new row

Tags: python, pandas

Working on a school project to predict college football games.The Y variable is point differential. I could use help in figuring out how to code the subtracting of one row from another with the row that is subtracted being located in the list by opponent name.

If team A's opponent is team b, subtract the x variables of team B from team A
for a new row called "Game Stats: Team A vs. Team B"
The new set of x variable values is the game stats or game differentials row. This would need to iterate for 130 teams.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

stats = pd.read_excel('/CFB_Final_Stats_07122020e.xlsm')
for stats.opponent == Team in stats:
  subtract opponent's x variables as "game_stats:" + "Team A" + "Opponent"
```

Here is an abbreviated sample of the layout:

[image: Sample Data]

Answer (score 0):

```
stats['Game Stats: Team A vs. Team B'] = stats['Team_score'] - stats['Opp Score']
```

Does that help? I think that's what you are looking for.